# splitting natural numbers into sets in other way than division

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Background: I am writing a web-scraper traversing sequential article-ids, for example from 3456 to 4567 (natural numbers). I have multiple scraper-servers running in parallel, each of which are supposed to cover a range of ids. To cover that I am using a bot instead of manually accessing articles, I want

- the range to be more or less random (thus not just dividing the total range by the number of servers)
- while staying mutually exclusive.
- the resulting sets should be iteratable and easy to compute, so when one server tells the load-balancer: "I did X number of requests", the load-balancer can compute without wasting too many resources, which IDs have been covered already

What mathematic function can I use for that?

Comment: This might be better asked over at Stack Overflow;  they probably have more experience with load-balancing algorithms than we do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a base 10 number of exactly 4 digits. If you iterated these, you'd have all IDs from 0000 to 9999. If you wish to distort the sequence in this list, consider a relabeling of the digits such that the symbol $9$ is 0, the symbol $2$ is 1, etc. Then your sequence is basically a counting sequence with a different set of symbols. Here's an example for two-digits where the least significant digit is first under the symbols of base 4 being $(3 0 2 1)$: $33,~ 03,~ 23,~ 13,~ 30,~ 00,~ 20,~ 10,~ 32,~ 02,~ 22,~ 12,~ 31,~ 01,~ 21,~ 11$.

These are trivial to compute in both directions, easy to store a state for resumption, easy to assign a range.